# Utilize Organization selection in custom portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to use Liferay's Organization `select/search` feature such as when adding a new user through the Control Panel (under Users and Organizations).

Does anyone know where that code lives? Trying to get a grasp on navigating their source code but can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the liferay OOTB portlets' JSPs lie in the folder [`portal-web/docroot/html/portlet`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet).

And all the implementation classes (service implementation) reside in the [`portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet) for respective portlets.

So keeping this convention in mind, the JSPs for the `Users & Organization` would reside in [`portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin) since you can't see any folder with the name `users` or `organizations` or `users_organization`, so your best bet is to look inside the `users_admin` folder, also because this folder has [`user`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/user) & [`organization`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/organization) folder which include specific JSPs for Users and Organizations.

In this folder you would find different `*search.jsp` & `*search_results.jsp` which would be what you might be looking for.

I would suggest always start looking from the [`view.jsp`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/view.jsp) for a particular portlet since this is the first landing page when we add the portlet to the page or click on any Control Panel portlets the first time. Most probably this `view.jsp` would include all the other JSPs which you might want to customize or take an idea from.

Most of the time the JSPs lead you to the implementation classes, we can't use liferay's implementation classes (since they live in `portal-impl.jar` and using this jar in plugin-portlets is prohibited) but we can use the different `*Util.java` classes which are exposed for our use like the `UserLocalServiceUtil`, `OrganizationLocalServiceUtil`, `OrganizationServiceUtil` etc.

Hope this gives a clue to finding out Liferay implementations.